# Bin File generation from keil IDE for STM32 MCU

Tags: development-environment, stm32, keil, firmware, ota

Hello EveryOne,
                I am working with STM32 MCU and need to generate the binary(.bin) file from the KEIL-IDE(Development tool chain) So that I can upload the new firmware file to the HTTP/FTP server to do the Firmware over the air(FOTA).

So, Please suggest/guide me that how to generate the binary(.bin) file from the KEIL-IDE.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Keil includes a tool to do it called fromelf, which is in the keil/ARM/ARMCC/bin directory

use `fromelf.exe --bin AXF_FILE_NAME --output BINARYFILENAME`

You can add it in a post build step if you want to automate it.

Comment: Hey Colin,
Thanks for your response.
After using command in keil-IDE  it shows the ERROR:
 "test3.axf": Error: Q0122E: Could not open file 'test3.axf': No such file or directory.

Comment: That's fairly self explanatory.  Check you have the path correct, if you're setting up as a post build step, the base directory is the directory your project is in. you may need obj/test3.axf or output/test3.axf or similar depending on how your project is set up.

Comment: Ok Colin,
You mean to say that I have to create a folder(directory) by using "obj/test3.axf" command to get the axf file in the obj folder(directory). Right ....!!! 
If I am going then let me know .... Gudie once again ...
Many Thanks ... Colin